# KeywordModelData instead of actual keyword returned in PCA query

Tags: dxa, keyword, graphql, pca

I am querying the PCA for Component Presentations in order to return the data via a service. I've found that the relevant data is available in

```
{
  edges {
    node {
      rawContent {
        data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that metadata is not coming back properly. For any metadata field where the value is selected from a drop-down or radio button list based off of a category/key, instead of entered as text, I'm getting the following data instead of the actual keyword name. How can I get the actual keyword name and value returned through a query?

```
"Metadata": {
  "brand": {
    "$type": "KeywordModelData",
      "Id": "634",
      "Namespace": "tcm"
      },
    "category": {
      "$type": "KeywordModelData",
      "Id": "1209",
      "Namespace": "tcm"
      },
```

Comment: Which version of Tridion are you using? It looks like you’re also using DXA. Which version?

Answer (score 2):

Your data looks a lot like DXA R2 JSON, so I assume you’re using DXA (TBBs at least)?

It also looks like the Categories are marked as publishable, in which case the TBBs will only include the Keyword IDs; the DXA Model Extension should take care of dynamically retrieving and expanding the Keyword Data.